# Is it possible that an enum is assigned unexpected value?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum like below :

```
    public enum ActionRole : int
    {
        Donor = 2501401,
        Recipient = 2501402,
        Wildcard = 2501403
    }

var temp = (ActionRole)1;
```

This line cannot give an error. I don't understand why. Because ActionRole Enum hasn't a value 1, How can 1 be cast ActionRole Enum ?  Can you explain this for me ?

Comment: `Is it possible that an enum is assigned unexpected value?` Yes. Try it and see.

Comment: Moreover, since the default value is `0`  the field `Test` contains unexpected value by default: `public class Demo {public ActionRole Test;}`

Comment: Use [`Enum.IsDefined`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx)